# C#.net Crystal Report run in Client Machine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a program in C#.Net using Visual Studio 2013 and I am using Crystal Report 13.
Now, my problem is when i tried to access the released folder in client machine I always got an error in Crystal report as shown in Image below:
By the way, I already tried to install crystal report run time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWzav.png)

Comment: Did you try different version of Crystal Report? I got the same error and was solved by changing the version of crystal report. I use VS2017 and using 13_0_21 . May be you should try 13_0_12

Comment: what is the version of your crystal report?

Comment: I already tried 13_0_21 and 13_0_12 but still not working on client machine,
the deployed program is the Released folder

Comment: I too deploy the release folder. Before installing another version of Crystal Report, first unistall the previously installed crystal report. I am using VS2017. So I cannot provide specific version of crystal report.

Comment: still encountering the same error hays